# Img not fading out jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some trouble with this JS / Jquery script, it was working completely yesterday, but today, it just wont work properly.

The loading `.gif` fades in, but just wont fade out...

This is my HTML

```
...
 <div class="banner">
    <img src="img/selosiade.png"/><br />
    <form>
        <input id="username" class="login" type="text" name="username" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Nome de Usu&aacute;rio"><br />
        <input id="password" class="login" type="password"  name"password" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Senha"><br />
        <input type="button" value="Login" onClick="login.db();">
        <img id="loading" src="img/loading.gif" />
...
```

(All tags are properly closed)

This what is set to the #loading id.

```
#loading{
    display:none;
    z-index:999;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:50px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

And this is the `login.db()` script:

```
var login = {
    db: function () {
        $('#loading').fadeIn(800, function () {

            if (($('#username').val().length === 0) && ($('#password').val().length === 0)) {
                $('#user_pass_vazio').fadeIn(800).delay(800).fadeOut(800);
                $('#loading').delay(800).fadeOut(800);
            } else if ($('#username').val().length === 0) {
                $('#user_vazio').fadeIn(800).delay(800).fadeOut(800);
                $('#loading').delay(800).fadeOut(800);
            } else if ($('#password').val().length === 0) {
                $('#pass_vazio').fadeIn(800).delay(800).fadeOut(800);
                $('#loading').delay(800).fadeOut(800);
            }

            var pass1 = $('#password').val();
            var pass = CryptoJS.SHA1(pass1);
            var user = $('#username').val();

            var flag = false;
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://apt-ghaschel.webatu.com/php/check.php",
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                data: {
                    user: user,
                    pass: pass
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    var b = msg.match(/^.*$/m)[0];
                    $('#store').text(b);
                    flag = true;
                }
            });

            if (flag) {
                return;
            }

            b = $('#store').text();
            if (b == '1') {
                $('#login_certo').fadeIn(800).delay(800).fadeOut(800, function () {
                    $('div.banner').fadeOut(800, function () {
                        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(pass, a);
                        $.cookie('username', user, {
                            expires: 365
                        });
                        $.cookie('username', encrypted, {
                            expires: 365
                        });
                        window.open("unidades.html?username=" + user + "");
                    });
                });
            } else if (b == '2') {
                $('#login_errado').fadeIn(800).delay(800).fadeOut(800, function () {});
            } else {
                $('#erro_desconhecido').fadeIn(800).delay(800).fadeOut(800);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Sorry if this is something silly, but I just can figure it out what is wrong.

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: Im using it on a Phonegap Project, it wont show any console =/

Comment: please, SSCCE. It seems it's not entering into any of your if/else blocks, and thus it never fades out.

Comment: It enter into a if / else block. It fades in and out the `#username`, `#user_vazio`, and `#pass_vazio` but the `#loading` wont fade out. I tried putind the `#loading` in front of the other codes, but it wont fade out.

Comment: try to create a http://jsfiddle.net/ that reproduces the error.

Comment: It's something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WK66p/2/ tried my best to make it looks like the actual project without uploading every single image im using...

Comment: @TheBronx and using `alert()` in front of any of the codes inside the blocks works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check whether this will help you, use

`$("#loading").stop().fadeOut(800);`

instead of

`$("#loading").delay(800).fadeOut(800);`

Answer (score 1):

The fade out works properly when I disable **CryptoJS** in your fiddle.

By the way, the login-form div doesn't fade in at the start. I suggest you to use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    pisca.telalogin();
});
```

Comment: Disabling CryptoJS didn't do anything here, but usint `.stop();` solved my problem. Thank you anyway.